# Expresion regular para string que comience y termine con un parentesis

Tags: javascript, string, regex

quisiera ayuda para crear una expresión regular para que haga match solamente con strings que empiecen y terminen con parentesis y que entre ellos solamente se admitan letras ignorando mayusculas-minusculas, lo he intentado de la siguiente manera

```
const regex = new RegExp(/^\([a-zA-Z]/)

const regex2 = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z]\)$/)
```

Si intento con el siguiente string:

```
regex.test('(Ho}la)')
```

me devulve string, pero no es lo que busco ya que hay un `}`.

Además como se haría para que quede en una sola expresión regular? He intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
const regex = new RegExp(/^\([a-zA-Z]\)$/)
```

pero si pruebo el siguiente string me devuelve `false`

```
regex.test('(Hola)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu última expresión está perfecta para lo que quieres, lo que tal y como está solo matcheará 1 solo caracter dentro del paréntesis. Para que te matchee **uno o más** debes colocar el símbolo de `+`. Quedaría `^\([a-zA-Z]+\)$`.

```js
const regex = /^\([a-zA-Z]+\)$/;
console.log(regex.test('(Hola)'))
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, no había tomado en cuanta el + para que haga match a uno o más, ahora sí funciona.